# Slide only Half view of view pager view in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

[image]

Is it possible to slide only half of view pager view on swiping ? 
or is it possible to make only one view per two view pager view ?

so that i wanted to half half sliding of view pager views. 
I want to show half of the View and when on touch The other half will be appear.

Comment: I am not quite certain what you are seeking, but it might relate to: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

Comment: Oh, that's the inverse of what I was thinking. I am not aware that this is possible. Why do you need the left half of "Page-2" and the right half of "Page-2" to be the same "page"? Why are those not just two separate pages, from the standpoint of `ViewPager`?

Comment: actually, i have one big image and it's size is double of screen width, i want to display half half part of image on swiping because i don't want to compromise with image quality, i also have perform all the bitmap operation to maintain image quality.

Comment: "Image quality" should not prevent you from splitting the image in half.

Comment: @Tejas have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would try to divide images into 2 bitmaps and load in separate views(or fragments) By this way you can get the same ui. You can do it easly with sdk's bitmap class in your adapter. Here is a little hint :[BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code in your view pager adapter.

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (0.5f);
    }
```

Comment: Could you develop a little?

Comment: This will not give you the half of a fragment but divided by 2 the current page to display 2 fragments at the same time. Then with your method, OP will need to use 6 fragments instead of 3 and don't have a half fragment on screen... And we return to the same situation!

Comment: @Fllo  i can't use 6 fragments because i am loading one big image per two views of view pager, can i device image using some methodology and display half half image per view ?